# Controlling WPF ListBox height without setting a specific value and while having row's height set to auto?

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, height

I'm curious if this can be done... I have a grid that contains several rows.  For various design reasons, I would like to maintain the height of the rows as `height="Auto"`.  Listbox is spanning across three rows within the grid. Unless I set its height to something specific (`height="70"`), while items are added or removed, it'll adjust its height dynamically, while also adjusting rows' heights, since they're set to `Auto`.  This is a normal behavior and everything is functioning as it should -- I'm just trying to get around that behavior.

Is there a way, at all, to have this ListBox stretch vertically within current height of the rows it occupies, while having no direct control over the rows' heights?  I understand that row's height property being set to `Auto` causes it to expand and contract based on its contents, but I'm wondering if I can prevent my ListBox from having that authority, while allowing other items to do their normal thing.

I can get a fairly precise static height on the ListBox to make the whole interface look good, but I was hoping to have it stretch and occupy the space of the designated row, while maintaing row's height as `Auto` and effected by any other content **except** that ListBox.

If it can't be done, does anyone have a suggestion for what I'm trying to accomplish?

**EDIT:**

Based on Sheridan's excellent answer, I was able to achieve the desired outcome.  Here's the code that made it all happen (also see Sheridan's code).

```
public class SumConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, 
                          System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        double sum = 0;

        foreach (var val in values)
        {
            sum += (double)val;
        }

        return sum;
    }


    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter,  
                                System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException(); // Didn't implement this part yet...
    }
}

<Window ....
        xmlns:c="clr-namespace:DSTG.Converters
        ....>

<Window.Resources>
    <c:HeightSumConverter x:Key="SumConverter"/>
<Window.Resources>

<ListBox>
    <ListBox.Height>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource SumConverter}">
            <Binding Path="ActualHeight" ElementName="txtDat1"/>
            <Binding Path="Margin.Bottom" ElementName="txtDat1"/>
            <Binding Path="ActualHeight" ElementName="txtDat2"/>
            <Binding Path="Margin.Bottom" ElementName="txtDat2"/>
            <Binding Path="ActualHeight" ElementName="txtDat3"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </ListBox.Height>
</ListBox>
```

The above code also accounts for the bottom margin of two of the three controls, so that everything aligns

Comment: Have you tried setting the VerticalAlignment to Stretch?

Comment: @jugg1es I have. Same behavior.  This is due to the fact that nothing is constraining ListBox's height and row is stretching with it due to its height="Auto" setting.

Comment: Do you know which control in that row will have maximum height? Have you tried binding listbox's height to this control's height?

Comment: @Athari No, I haven't.  But I have after you and Sheridan mentioned it and it works very well.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to data bind the `ListBox.Height` property to the `ActualHeight` of another control that takes the same space:

```
<ListBox Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=AnotherControlOfTheRightHeight}" />
```

If you don't have another control spanning 3 rows, you could make a simple [`IMultiValueConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that returns the sum of the input values and data bind to several controls:

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.Height>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource SumConverter}">
            <Binding Path="ActualHeight" ElementName="Control1" />
            <Binding Path="ActualHeight" ElementName="Control2" />
            <Binding Path="ActualHeight" ElementName="Control3" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </ListBox.Height>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Brilliant! It worked like a charm.  I'll post my code up in my original post so that others can see what I did.  Thank you so much.

Comment: I have one more question.  How would I account for margin height of the three controls as well?  Slight misalignment occurs since ListBox is spanning accorss thee rows, so it doesn't account for the margin between the other three controls.

Comment: You certainly could do that, although it'll bit a fair bit more work for you. There's no reason why you can't make your `Converter` more complex... I have one that adds `double` values with `Size` dimensions for similarly complicated UI layouts. So you could just bind to the controls `Margin` property as well and your `Converter` will have to bear in mind that the input might be `double` *or* `Thickness`, in which case, it would have to extract the `double` from the `Thickness`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. For now, I just went with a simple route.  See my edited post.

Comment: You're welcome and thanks for updating your question with the resolution. I feel that this improves the quality of posts on this site.